# MySQL Show Message If ID Entries Not Found

Tags: php, mysqli

My original question was not clear enough. SO I'll attempt to give more information. I have a page that pulls data from a database using PHP (default.php). I built this page so that, based on the 'ID' - the content will change on the page. This is because I will have 100+ entries. I don't want to create 100 individual pages since the only the content will be changing.

Example:

```
https://mywebsite.com/default.php?id=xxxxx1
https://mywebsite.com/default.php?id=xxxxx2
https://mywebsite.com/default.php?id=xxxxx3
```

etc...

My table have columns for each row including:
'id'
'name'
'image'
'nominations'
etc...

The 'default.php' page is a template that has the following code:

In the header:

```
<?php
include_once '../dbh.php';
 $id = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

And in the body for each of the columns above:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT nominations FROM channel_info";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nominations FROM channel_info WHERE id='$id'");
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $row['nominations'];            
   }
} else {
   echo "<p>Sorry. No nominations listed. </p>";
}
?>
```

etc..

Currently the messages does NOT show when columns in the same row of the table is empty. How can I make this message show so that if it's empty it will display a message? This happens to all the data entries.

Empty column: [screenshot] prnt.sc/tkcw80
Page displa: [screenshot] http://prntscr.com/tk54iv

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you give us a better example? Can you tell what data you are dealing with?

Comment: @Dharman Sorry. I work PHP before, but this is my first time using it to pull from a database. I'm trying to have an if/else statement where 'if' data exist show data. 'else' show a message: "nothing found". 

The data is just text data. If I understand your question.

So using screenshots from my example:
[data exist and displays data]: http://prntscr.com/tk5f8r
[data does not exist and does not display message]: http://prntscr.com/tk54iv
 

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: First, if you are only starting please learn PDO instead of mysqli. Your code should display a message, so you need to explain to us what is wrong. Do you see "Sorry. No nominations listed." at all?

Comment: @Dharman My fault. My comment sent before hitting finishing my comment. 

So using screenshots from my example: [data exist and displays data]: prntscr.com/tk5f8r [data does not exist and does not display message]: prntscr.com/tk54iv Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Do you ever see the message "Sorry. No nominations listed." or not?

Comment: @Dharman No I  do not see it.

Comment: Then it means you always have at least one record. `mysqli_num_rows` tells you the number of records fetched from the database. If it is greater than 0 it means you fetched at least 1 record

Comment: What you posted *should* work. What's the value of `$id` and where is it coming from? Are you checking for errors at all on the PHP and the query? I don't see any of that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner $Id is referring to $_GET. This code is at the top of my page. /// <?php include_once '../dbh.php'; $id = $_GET['id']; ?> When I view console I don't see any error.

Comment: @Dharman  I restructured the question and hopefully it's more understandable.

Comment: What do you mean columns are empty? Can you show full code which prepared that table?

Comment: @Dharman Database row [screenshot] https://prnt.sc/tkcw80  Regarding the table, do you mean the PHP code? That's all I have those two blocks. One in the header and the other in the body.

Comment: `if(!$row['nominations']) echo "No nominations!";`

Comment: Is this what you want? https://3v4l.org/Lg85P

Comment: @Dharman Oh my god! Yes. That's what I waned. It works. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

> > I'll try to help you but first, could you please tell me what $id is referring to ? $_GET ? $_POST ? ...
> > it could be a security issue.

So, if you would like to connect to your database I would suggest you to use PHP PDO like so :

```
define('user', "HERE_YOUR_USER");
define('password', "HERE_YOUR_PASSWORD");
define('DB_name', "HERE_YOUR_DATABASE_NAME");

// REPLACE "localhost:8889" WITH YOUR SERVER:PORT
define('DB_server', "localhost:8889");

try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_server.";dbname=".DB_name, user, password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Then, you would like to make a request :

```
$results = $connect->prepare("SELECT nominations FROM channel_info WHERE id='$id'");
if ($results->execute()) {
    while ($r = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $r['nominations'];
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Sorry. No nominations listed. </p>";
}
```

Let me know if you have any question about it :)

Comment: $Id is referring to $_GET. This code is at the top of my page.

///
<?php
 include_once '../dbh.php';
  $id = $_GET['id'];
 ?>

Comment: Imagine if someone write on the url : http://YourWebsite.com/index.php?id=A_VERY_MEAN_SQL_REQUEST_THAT_WE_BE_ADDED_FOLLOWING_YOUR_ORIGINAL_REQUEST.  It could be a real problem for you, isn't ? this is what we call "sql injection" that's dangerous. Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks for the info. I never thought this would be an issue as my site is particulary small

Comment: Awesome. I've just modified a little bit the code that I've posted, I made it more readable. Let me know it doesn't work.